# Run Windows 8.1 app on another machine

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

Can I run my Windows 8.1 app on another machine outside of Visual Studio and without going through the Store. I need it for testing.

I tried

- Run executable files from Debug and Release folders.
- Create an app package and run files from it.

It's all didn't work for me.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can run/debug a Windows Store app on a remotely connected machine. It must have a developer's license and the Visual Studio Remote Tools installed. More information available here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx

Alternatively, if you are running Windows 8.1 Professional or Enterprise on a domain then there are various ways to sideload store apps: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/jj874388.aspx